# Combining two RegEx in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two JS RegExes `/\?(?!xml)/ig` which looks for any ? not followed by string "xml" and another `/\?(?!>)/ig` which looks for ? not followed by ">".

How do I combine both into a single regular expression?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?  A then B, A or B, A and B,...

Comment: A or B. Sorry if it was unclear. I got the solution anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
/\?(?!(xml|>))/gi
```

**Edit:** In any case consider parsing your XML properly with a parser instead of RegExp.

Comment: @elclanrs : Bang on! I just came to update the same expression. /\?(?!(xml|>))/ig